# Skype ChatBot Bubble - Different message colors

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

So I've been using MS Bot Framework to build some chatbots and I'm trying to integrate one of them with Skype.
The thing is, it seems that the "Skype Bubbles" don't support different color messages to distinguish between the user & the bot.
Even the default Skype bot has all messages in grey.

Is it possible to change this?

Thank you all.

Example of Skype's Test Bot Color Scheme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at on the https://dev.skype.com website (aka Skype Dev Buddy bot) is actually the Skype Web Chat component. You can achieve some degree of customization using the [chat control customization tool here.](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol)

If you would like full control over the styling of the chat control, you can fork and customize the Bot Framework official WebChat module (which is different than the Skype Web Chat (SWC).

For more information on customizing the [Bot Framework WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) component, see: [Customizing WebChat > Styling](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#customizing-webchat)

Comment: Thanks but I know that. I was asking about this particular case of the Skype Web Chat Component. It's customizable but it's lacking the key part of being able to differentiate between user & bot text colors.

Comment: @Francisco You can't do that with the Skype Web Control, you would need to use the Bot Framework WebChat module and customize the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible to do that with Skype Web Control as @Nils W said.
One should use the Bot Framework WebChat Module.